# How are printing functions made?

Tags: printing, programming-languages

I am making my own programming language, and how can I print characters on screen?
When I try to print using video memory (0xB8000) program crashes...

Comment: Writing directly to video memory is how it was done in the old days before protected-mode operating systems became common,  If you really want to try stuff that way, you could use `dosemu` under Linux.   Perhaps `VirtualBox` with a free version of `DOS` installed..  But if you want answers here, you better say what operating system you plan on running in

Comment: In fact, if you were really working on a bare metal PC.  The 'official 'way to print to the screen in bare-metal, pre-OS mode, would be to use BIOS calls via INT 10 H.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H   Not exactly the most fun way to do things

Answer (score 1):

Erm, no don't do that. This is how an operating system can print stuff to the screen, but I doubt it would allow you to do the same without some kind of segmentation violation.

If you just want to print text to the screen, and assuming you are on a UNIX like system, either use the `write`[1] system call, or just open the standard output file (`stdout`, assuming your language allows you to open files) and write there.

[1]: This is the signature for write: `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);`. For more information, [read this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)